# How to compile a JavaBean?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm learning JavaBeans and it's application I'm creating my first ever Bean, I use an IDE called **JCreator(free)** which I have been using so far for the the compilation process of Servlets and I transfer the `.class` file to the local Apache server.

In my lecture notes it states that I need to store the JavaBeans I create in a package, which according to my understanding should reside inside the JDK version I use, am I right?
The notes talk about the following command to line method for this

```
javac -d. newBean.java
```

I use a local folder in my E: drive to store all the Java files I create and compile them there, obviously I move the class files in to the classes folder in my WEB-INF in my Apache which is located in local C:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve the assignment requirements.

Assuming a directory structure as follows:

```
C:\projects\stackoverflow\3748425>dir /s
 Volume in drive C is WINVISTA
 Volume Serial Number is 3079-C372

 Directory of C:\projects\stackoverflow\3748425

09/19/2010  07:55 PM              .
09/19/2010  07:55 PM              ..
09/19/2010  07:56 PM              beans
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\projects\stackoverflow\3748425\beans

09/19/2010  07:56 PM              .
09/19/2010  07:56 PM              ..
09/19/2010  07:58 PM               540 Bean1.class
09/19/2010  07:57 PM               357 Bean1.java
               2 File(s)            897 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               2 File(s)            897 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  170,347,962,368 bytes free
```

And a Java source code file...

```
package beans;

public class Bean1 implements java.io.Serializable {

  private String a;
  private String b;

  public Bean1(){}

  public void setA(String a){
    this.a = a;
  }

  public void setB(String b){
    this.b = b;
  }

  public String getA(){
    return this.a;
  }

  public String getB(){
    return this.b;
  }

}
```

You can compile it with this command:

```
javac -d . beans\Bean1.java
```

Comment: Hi JT thanks for the reply; my directory structure where all my java files and class files are saved is as follows: E:\Personal\BInfoTech\Practicals\Java this is my current location, assuming this can you please explain to my how to copile the Bean, as usual my JDK is in C:\

Comment: @Kushan - I was basing my answer on the information provided from the lecture notes and the fact that you listed the "javac -d ." command. In my experience, professors prefer the JDK programs (javac, java) to the use of IDEs. Try taking my example and saving it in your E:\Personal\BInfoTech\Practicals\Java\beans\Bean1.java and use the listed javac command from the directory E:\Personal\BInfoTech\Practicals\Java. This assumes that the JDK\bin directory is in your environment path. The result should be a Java class in E:\Personal\BInfoTech\Practicals\Java\beans\Bean1.class. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks JT, that certainly helps, funny you say that, our lecturer actualy wanted us to use the IDE

Comment: You are welcome Kushan. The lecturer knows best. IDEs generally make Java development much, much smoother :)

Comment: JT, thought I'd let you know, it works like a charm, I wrote the code in the IDE but compiled using your method in command line, thanks again

Comment: That's great news Kushan. Does JCreator compile it too?

Comment: No JCreator as in the case of most IDE a set path that is defined at the installation of the software, which can be changed, but it's too much trouble \, much more feasible to do it on command line